# Another use of ellipsis in English (not in previous questions)

Tags: ellipsis

Today I have come across an English sentence: "It is broken up into many independent countries warring over many issues". Note that there is no comma there.
Since "warring" can be only adjective, if there is not the phrase "over many issues", I think  the sentence must be: "It is broken up into many independent warring countries".
So my question is that can we always use ellipsis like in the above sentence when we have an adjective phrase?
If yes, is the sentence below OK?
"These are beautiful girls attractive at first sight."

Comment: I'd say no, you can't do that in all contexts. Take *"Parliament is composed of many independent parties **promoting their own agendas***. That certainly can't be reduced to *...many independent **promoting** parties.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd think using "promoting" in your sentence is another story. It is a v-ing form.

Comment: @Ng "warring" is used as an adjective, however it is created from the verb **to war**. It is a verb+ing form.

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes, thanks a lot. This fools my questions. I checked both OALD and CALD and found that "war" is not a verb. But now, Merriam-Webster shows that "war" is also a verb. What great dictionaries!

Comment: Not all verbs can be used in all contexts, obviously. *Democracies rarely war* is grammatically valid, but would *anyone* ever say or write it? I think not. (Present company and context excepted, of course! :)

Comment: The verb war isn't used as much today, it's somewhat obsolete, but you will still find it listed in good dictionaries, such as Merriam-Webster or the OED. And you will find it used in older literature - obsolete, but still understood.  The verb is the origin of the -ing form.